# Using findText() in QWebengineView to find and select strings in htmlpage

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtwebengine

I have a problem with using findText() of QWebengineView.
I want to build a program, where I can search an HTML Page for specific words, mark them up, and extract them by using the selectedText() method of QWebengineview/page.

findText() works fine for searching the page and marking up all occurences of the words on the page. The words are found and the callback function shows "TRUE" for the callback "found". But when I call selectedText() the string is always empty, so nothing is selected on the page. Maybe I'm using the callback function wrong?

```
class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        '''Initializer of Main App'''
        super(App, self).__init__()
        self.resize(1920, 1080)
        self.view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(self)
        self.view.resize(1920, 1080)

        self.url = QUrl('https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Phelps')
        self.view.load(self.url)

        self.button = QPushButton(self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.searchPage)
        
        self.button2 = QPushButton(self)
        self.button2.move(40,40)
        

    def searchPage(self):
        flags = QWebEnginePage.FindFlags(0)
        self.view.findText("Michael", flags ,self.callback)
    
    def callback(self, found):
        print(found)
        print(self.view.page().selectedText())
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please include your code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Can you show some sample HTML you will be working with?

Comment: Sites im using to test are e.G. wikipedia pages. In this Case the one of Michael Phelps: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Phelps

Answer (score 1):

The text found through the [`findText()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#findText) function is **highlighted**, it is **not selected**, which is why the [`selectedText()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#selectedText-prop) method returns an empty string. On the other hand, the [`findText()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#findText) method would theoretically return the highlighted text that is the same text that you used when starting the search, so expecting it to be different is useless, so the callback only returns a Boolean indicating that there is or not an element that matches the word.

Comment: Yeah I know its highlighted. But the problem is, its only highlighted as long no new string is searched for. I want to search the page for a string, hihglight it and then search for the next string and highlight it. So in the end all my search querys are highlighted.

Comment: @radarjonathan mmm, that's not what your post points to. I think you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You could be more direct in your request and not think about your possible solution that nobody guarantees will work. To be practical in your example you use the word "Michael", what do you hope to get when the nth word "Michael" is highlighted? for example what should happen if the first "Michael" is highlighted.

Comment: So what could I do, if I want to select the highlighted text of findText()?

Comment: @radarjonathan Okay, I think I'm understanding better what you want, you want the highlighted text to be selected as well, am I correct? If so, then for example when you use findText then "n" words are highlighted but there is more highlighted text, which one do you want highlighted: the "n" highlighted words or only the most highlighted word?

Comment: Yes exactly. I want to to search the page for a word e.g. "Michael", so n occurences of "Michale" are highlighted. Then I want to search another word, e.G. "swimming". So I want all my search results of my previous search for "Michael" highlighted and also the new words found for "swimming" highlighted. The Problem is the Moment i search for "swimming" findText() deletes the old highlights.

Comment: Now you've confused me more. Do you want the previously searched text highlighted as "Michael" to remain highlighted even when searching for a new text such as "swimming"? Please understand: **In html highlighted is not the same as selected.**

Comment: Yes I want the search results for "Michael" highlighted even when im searching for something new. I thought if could select the results for "Michael" i could highlight them with JS or something else and then call findText() again and select all the results for e.G. "swimming" again so i can highlight them. and so on